# Reportes vacios

Tags: python, mvc, xml, odoo

Estoy haciendo un popup en odoo pero estoy haciendo un filtrado para extraer cierta información de un modelo en especifico pero de diferentes formas es decir una sola pantalla para mostrar diferentes tipos de información depende de la selección que se haga es el reporte que descarga pero estuve haciendo unos cuantos arreglos y aun no logro solucionarlo

Adjunto codigo del modelo:

```
import json
import io
from xlsxwriter import workbook

from odoo.tools import date_utils
from odoo import fields, models, api
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
 try:
from odoo.tools.misc import xlsxwriter
except ImportError:
import xlsxwriter


class SaleReportAdvance(models.TransientModel):
_name = "sale_report_general"


from_date = fields.Date(string="Fecha de cotizacion")
to_date = fields.Date(string='Vencimiento')
type = fields.Selection(
    [('General', 'General'), ('Executive', 'Executive'), ('Country', 'Country')],
    string='Buscar por', default='General', reqired=True)
seller_id = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='hr.employee', string='Ejecutivo')
country_arrival = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='res.country', string='Destino')



def _get_data (self):
    sale = self.env['sale.order'].search([('state', '!=', 'cancel')])
    if self.from_date and self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() >= self.from_date and x.date_order.date() <= self.to_date,
                                  sale))
    elif not self.date_order and self.validity_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() <= self.validity_date,
                                  sale))
    elif self.date_order and not self.validity_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() >= self.date_order,
                                  sale))
    elif self.date_order and self.to_date :
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() >= self.validity_date and x.date_order.date() <= self.to_date,
                                  sale))
    elif not self.date_order and self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() <= self.validity_date,
                                  sale))
    elif self.date_order and not self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() >= self.date_order,
                                  sale))
    else:
        sales_order = sale
    result = []
    seller = []
    country = []
    for rec in self.seller_id:
        a = {
            'id': rec,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        seller.append(a)
    for rec in self.country_arrival:
        a = {
            'id': rec,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        country.append(a)
        if self.type == 'Executive':
            for rec in seller:
                for lines in sale:
                    if lines.seller_id == rec['id']:
                        if lines.seller_id:
                         res = {
                             'name': name,
                             'date': date_order,
                             'consignee': lines.name.consignee_id.name,
                             'seller': lines.name.seller_id.name,
                             'country': lines.name.country_arrival.name,
                             'freight': lines.name.freight_type,
                             'gross': lines.name.gross_weight,
                             'volume': lines.name.volume,
                             'invoice': lines.name.invoice_amount_assured,
                             'partner_id': so.partner_id.name
                        }
                        result.append(res)
        if self.type == 'Country':
            for rec in country:
                for so in sales_order:
                    if so.country_arrival == rec['id']:
                        for lines in so.order_line:
                            if lines.country_arrival:
                             res = {
                                 'sequence': name,
                                 'date': date_order,
                                 'partner_id': so.partner_id,
                                 'validity': so.validity_date,
                                 'consignee': lines.name.consignee_id.name,
                                 'seller': lines.name.seller_id.name,
                                 'country': lines.name.country_arrival.name,
                                 'freight': lines.name.freight_type,
                                 'gross': lines.name.gross_weight,
                                 'volume': lines.name.volume,
                                 'invoice': lines.name.invoice_amount_assured
                             }
                            result.append(res)
        if self.type == 'General':
             for rec in seller:
                for p in seller:
                    for so in sales_order:
                        if so.partner_id == rec['id']:
                            for lines in so.date_order:
                                if lines.date_order == p['id']:
                                    if lines.date_order:

                                     res = {
                                         'name': name,
                                         'date': date_order,
                                         'partner': so.partner_id.name,
                                         'validity': so.validity_date,
                                         'consignee': lines.name.consignee_id.name,
                                         'seller': lines.name.seller_id.name,
                                         'country': lines.name.country_arrival.name,
                                         'freight': lines.name.freight_type,
                                         'gross': lines.name.gross_weight,
                                         'volume': lines.name.volume,
                                         'invoice': lines.name.invoice_amount_assured
                                     }
                                    result.append(res)

                        data = {
                           'ids': self,
                           'model': 'sale_report_general',
                           'form': result,
                           'seller_id': seller,
                           'country_arrival': country,
                           'type': self.type,
                           'no_value': False
                        }
                        return data

def get_ventas_report(self):
  data = self._get_data()
  logger.info('**************************************************************Obtuvo el informe de ventas')
  return self.env.ref('sale_report_terrestre.action_general_report').report_action(self, data=data)

  if self.date_order and self.validity_date and not self.seller_id and not self.country_arrival:
        data['no_value']=True
        return data
```

esa es la estructura que estoy ocupando para el modelo si yo eligo general solo debe de buscar por un rango  de fechas y es por ejecutuvi osolo se le agrega el no0mbre del ejecutivo y lo mismo pasa cuando se selecciona por destino pero solo me funciona la parte de general pero en la vista cuando yo selecciono general y solo lo busco por el rango de fechas lo manda vcio pero si yo selecciono un ejecutivo y un destio solo muestra la tabla y no la informacion

Adjunto vista xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<record id="general_wizard" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Sales General Report</field>
    <field name="model">sale_report_general</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <group >
                <field name="from_date"/>
                <field name="to_date"/>
                <field name="type" widget="radio"/>
            </group>
            <group>
                <field name="seller_id" widget="many2many_tags" attrs="{'invisible': [('type', '=', 'Country')]}"/>
                <field name="country_arrival" widget="many2many_tags" attrs="{'invisible': [('type', '=', 'Executive')]}"/>
            </group>
            <footer>
                <button name="get_ventas_report" string="PDF Report" type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
<record id="sale_general_report" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">General Sales Report</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">sale_report_general</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="general_wizard"/>
    <field name="target">new</field>
</record>
  </odoo>
```

no se si en la vista tenga que agregar una validacion para que cuando selecciobne general solo busque por fechas

Adjutno  codigo de los reportes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<template id="sales_general_view">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
       <div class="header" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
           <h3 class="text-center">Sales General Report
               <span style="font-size: 14px;"><storng>From</storng>:<t t-esc="from_date"/> <strong>To</strong>: <t t-esc="to_date"/></span>
           </h3>
           <div class="article mt0 o_report_layout_standard">
               <t t-if="type == 'General'">
                     <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <th style="width:30%">Date</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Folio</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Remitente</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Consignatario</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Destino</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Volumen</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Peso_Bruto</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Seguro</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Factura</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Monto Fact</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Vencimineto</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Ejecutivo</th>
                       </thead>
                        <t t-foreach="General" t-as="order">
                         <tr>
                           <td><span t-esc="order['date_order']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['name']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['partner_id']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['consignee_id']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['country_arrival']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['volume']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['gross_weight']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['freight_assured']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['freight_type']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['invoice_amount_assured']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['validity_date']"/></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['seller_id']"/></td>
                          </tr>
                        </t>
                    </table>
               </t>
               <t t-if="type == 'Executive'">
                 <h3>
                    <span style="font-size: 14px;"><storng>Ejecutivo</storng>:<t t-esc="seller_name"/></span>
                </h3>
               <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                   <thead>
                       <th style="with:30%">Date</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Folio</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Remitente</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Consignatario</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Destino</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Volumen</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Peso_Bruto</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Factura</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Monto Fact</th>
                   </thead>
                   <t t-foreach="seller_id" t-as="seller">
                       <tr>
                           <td><span t-esc="seller['date_order']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['name']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['partner_id']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['consignee_id']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['country_arrival']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['volume']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['gross_weight']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['freight_type']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['invoice_amount_assured']"/></td>
                       </tr>
                   </t>
               </table>
               </t>
               <t t-if=" type == 'Country'">
           <h3>
               <span style="font-size: 14px;"><storng>Destino</storng>:<t t-esc="seller_name"/></span>
           </h3>
               <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                   <thead>
                       <th style="with:30%">Date</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Folio</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Remitente</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Consignatario</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Destino</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Volumen</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Peso_Bruto</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Factura</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Monto Fact</th>
                   </thead>
                   <t t-foreach="country_arrival" t-as="Country">
                       <tr>
                           <td><span t-esc="Country['date_order']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="Country['name']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="Country['partner_id']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="Country['consignee_id']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="Country['country_arrival']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="Country['volume']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="Country['gross_weight']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="Country['freight_type']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="Country['invoice_amount_assured']"/></td>
                       </tr>
                   </t>
               </table>
               </t>
           </div>
           <div class="footer o_standard_footer" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
               <div class="row text-center">
                   <div class="col col-12 text-center">
                       <ul class="list-inline">
                           <li class="list-inline-item">Page:</li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">
                               <span class="page"/>
                           </li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">/</li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">
                               <span class="topage"/>
                           </li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </t>
</template>
  </odoo>
```

y asi es como tengo estructurado el reporte de iguak forma depende de la seleccion es la tabla que descarga pero el unico reporte que descarga es el general solo si esta lleno el campo de ejecutivo y destino pero si yo selecciono solo pr ejecutivo o destino no muestra la tabla solo muestra el encabezado y el pie de pagina que puedo hacer aqui para resolverlo